# Rmd file showing raw HTML when knitting (Shiny HTML)

Tags: html, r, shiny, r-markdown

I have this following html for a navbar:

```
<nav>
    <a class="toggle" href="#"><i class="fa fa-reorder"></i></a>
    <div class="navigate">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="link" id="click" href="#data-prep">Data Preparing</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" id="click" href="#plots">Related Plots</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" id="click" href="#players">Players Selection</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" id="click" href="#conclusion">Conclusion</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

However, when knitting to a Shiny HTML page, it doesn't get displayed, instead showing the raw html.
[image: Error]

I don't know what the issue is, sometimes it works with other html codes for navbar, but it doesn't work for this particular instance. I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Remove the indentations.

Comment: In what part? I think I pasted and didn't indent the html correctly

Comment: Remove all the indentations of the html code.